# What partial orders on tagged partitions generate the Riemann Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory, riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

Let $[a,b]$ be a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$, and let $X$ be the set of tagged partitions of $[a,b]$.  Now let’s define two partial orders over $X$.  Let $P_1\geq_1 P_2$ if $P_1$ is a refinement of $P_2$ and let $P_1\geq_2 P_2$ if the mesh of $P_1$ is less than or equal to the mesh of $P_2$. ($\geq_2$ is a total order, but of course total orders are also partial orders.)

Using these two partial orders, we can make two equivalent definitions of the Riemann integral:

1. We say that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = I$ if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a partition $P_c$ such that for all partitions $P\geq_1 P_c$, $|R(f,P)-I|<\epsilon$.
2. We say that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = I$ if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a partition $P_c$ such that for all partitions $P\geq_2 P_c$, $|R(f,P)-I|<\epsilon$.

Where $R(f,P)$ is the Riemann sum of $f$ over $P$. But my question is, what other partial orders on the set of tagged partitions would produce an equivalent definition of the Riemann integral?

I noticed that $\geq_1$ is a “suborder” of $\geq_2$.  That is, $P_1\geq_1 P_2$ implies $P_1\geq_2 P_2$, because a refinement of a partition will have a smaller mesh.  Is there any suborder $\geq_0$ of $\geq_1$ that produces an equivalent definition of the Riemann integral?

Comment: The orders which you have mentioned are ones found in literature. I wonder if any other sort of order on partitions has been studied.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I wonder whether if two orders produce equivalent definitions of the Riemann integral, that implies something about the relationship between the two orders, like a suborder relation or something else.

Comment: The given two orders are "natural" as one comes directly from set inclusion and the other from the metric. I suppose something like the transitive hull of "is obtained by splitting each subinterval into sevenpieces" would work

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If there are multiple suborders of $\geq_1$ that would work, is there a minimal suborder of $\geq_1$ that would work?

Comment: By the way the same two orders are not equivalent for Riemann Stieltjes integral and the order 1 is more general here.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan There is certainly no minimal suborder of $\ge_1$ that produces the same notion of integral. For example, taking a partial order that produces the standard Riemann integral and making a specific partition $P$ incomparable to all other partitions produces a proper suborder (if $P$ was comparable to another partition before, of course) that still produces the Riemann integral (for changing $f$ at the finitely many points of $P$ does not change its integrability or integral).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you give me an example where the two orders are not equivalent for the Riemann Stieltjes integral?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: This is from Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis* (page 174, Exercise 7.3). Let $f(x) =g(x) =0$ for $a\leq x<c$ and $f(x) =g(x) =1$ for $c<x\leq b$ and $f(c) =0, g(c)=1$. Then $\int_{a} ^{b} f\, dg$ exists according to the definition based on partial order $\geq_1$ but not according to the definition based on the other partial order $\geq_2$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Oh ok, and which one is the standard definition?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: as far as I know the definition based on $\geq_2$ is more popular/prevalent than the one based on $\geq_1$. Riemann also used the definition based on $\geq_2 $ for his integral.